# ASP.NET MVC Html.BeginForm to Insert new database record via ActionMethod

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

When I press the submit 'Create' button the page refreshes and nothing happens and it's like the form doesn't even call the controller 'SaveProject' actionresult. Nothing is inserted into the database.

I have noticed the URL given in the browser when I click the submit button is "http://localhost:62234/Operations/CreateProjectView?ProjectName=bhihi"

Shouldnt it be SaveProject instead? Why isit not directing it to the correct URL? When I enter the following URL: "http://localhost:62234/Operations/SaveProject?ProjectName=bhihi"

It creates a project and works fine. But for some reason the form is not calling the correct name??

Here is my code:
**OperationsController:**

```
   public ActionResult CreateProjectView()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SaveProject(Project model)
    {

        try
        {

            IRISInSiteLiveEntities DB = new IRISInSiteLiveEntities();

            Project newproject = new Project();

            newproject.ProjectName = model.ProjectName;


            DB.Projects.Add(newproject);
            DB.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("CreateProjectView");

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

CreateNewProject View:

```
 @model IRIS.Models.Project

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "CreateProjectView";
     Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

<div class="page-wrapper nope" style="background-image: url(../assets/images/background/AdobeStock_56278.png); background-size:auto">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-body">

                            @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveProject", "Operations", FormMethod.Post))
                            {

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 offset-lg-2">
                                                <label class="control-label">Project Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { @class = "form-control", Style = "text-align:center" })
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 offset-lg-2">
                                                <label class="control-label">Network Operator</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 offset-lg-2">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia Customer</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 offset-lg-2">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia Project Business Manager</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 offset-lg-2">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia Cost and Progress Manager</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 offset-lg-2">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia Procurement Manager</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-6">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia PDM</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia Project Manager</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Nokia Project Engineer</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Iris Project No</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Iris Project Manager</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
                                                <label class="control-label">Iris Project Engineer</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <br /><br />

                                <div class="col-2 offset-lg-1 pull-left">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info"  value="Create" style="width:100%; height:50px; padding: 5px" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
                        </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are no errors or anything. No exceptions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You migh wanna use **Http decorators** in your controller.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateProjectView()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateProject(Project model)
{
    try
    {
        // This should be your repository.
        var DB = new IRISInSiteLiveEntities();

        var newProject = new Project
        {
            ProjectName = model.ProjectName
        };

        DB.Projects.Add(newproject);
        DB.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("CreateProjectView");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And you view should be something like this (this is just your part):

```
@model IRIS.Models.Project

<form asp-controller="Operations" asp-action="CreateProject" id="operationsForm" method="post">

            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProjectName">Project Name</label>
                <input asp-for="ProjectName" class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NetworkOperator">NetworkOperator</label>
            </div>

            ...

            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default">
            </div>
</form>
```

Now, I don't remember exactly, but this is kinda 'newer' razor syntax (I don't use Razor). It looks more like HTML and it's a lot more cleaner. You will have to look up on the Internet for this.

What you also should look is **Repository pattern**. I asume that `IRISInSiteLiveEntities` is your repository. This should implement method like `CreateProject()` so that way you don't write directly from your Controller - that's not the job of the Controller.

So, your Controller should look something like this:

```
private readonly IRISInSiteLiveEntities m_siteLiveEntities;

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CreateProjectView()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateProject(Project model)
{
    try
    {
        var newProject = new Project
        {
            ProjectName = model.ProjectName
        };

        m_siteLiveEntities.CreateProject(newProject);

        return RedirectToAction("CreateProjectView");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

And again, look for **MVC Architecture design**, **Repository pattern** and even **Clean Architecture (Onion Architecture)**.

Comment: I have found the issue! If I change the section where it defines the layout on the page to NULL it all works fine. So something in the layout breaking it?

Comment: @Zack  I cant'exactly remember how to use _Layout, but that's something that is shared for all view pages - so you only define it once. In the _Layout you should have @RenderBody() part which rendersr your specific pages.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed the Layout = to NULL the form worked. When I looked in the _Layout.cshtml the page was enclosed in a  tag. Once I removed this the form works. Stupid me.